# Updated global variables does not reflect inside ValueEventListener's onCancelled method

Tags: java, android, firebase, global-variables

I am currently testing a ValueEventListener's `onCancelled()` method to implement proper firebase error management. I have succeeded thus far, onCancelled() was firing well. I have set-up the firebase rules for a specific node to return a permission denied error.

But I'm confused as to how global variables are managed inside the onCancelled() method. Why does it seem like global variables retain their default initial state when called inside `onCancelled()`? Updates on the variables from outside do not reflect when they're called inside this method but are reflected when called from `onDataChange()` and other in-Activity methods.

**UPDATE NO. 2:** 
Inserted the firebase auth codes, added test flow execution. Also added the log outputs as suggested by @Doug Stevenson. From the logs, it seems onCancelled() was only called once (during app onCreate()). I think that's what gave me the wrong impression that `currentSynId` was never changed coz its value is still `Hello!!!` there, and I didn't look at the after-logs before.

But now I see there's a log  `W/RepoOperation: updateChildren at /2014 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied` that fires everytime `R.id.btn_sync` is called (and never again the log for `onCancelled` where the updated `currentSyncId` should be). Maybe I should rephrase my question? I would like to catch the instance where/when the current cancellations logs are fired. Thanks.

**UPDATE NO. 1** I took out relevant pieces from the complete codes and replaced the previous snippets:

```
...

public class Demo extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Database reference
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseMain2014;

    //
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    public String currentSyncId = "Hello!!!";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

        // Initialize firebase auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    Log.d("MAIN", "A user was logged in: " + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    initDatabase(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                }


                findViewById(R.id.btn_sync).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        syncData();
                    }
                });

                findViewById(R.id.btn_echovalue).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        printId();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Initialize database and listeners
     * @param userid
     */
    public void initDatabase(String userid){
        Log.d("MAIN", "Initialized databases");
        // Initialize database references
        mFirebaseMain2014 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("2014");
        mFirebaseMain2014.child("app_final/" + userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // data processing here..
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("MAIN-ON-CANCELLED-EVENT", "An error occurred while syncing data: " +
                        databaseError.getMessage() + "\n id: " + currentSyncId);
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Initiate firebase syncing (which will lead to Permission-Denied
     */
    public void syncData(){
        // Log values
        Log.d("MAIN", "Initiating sync...");
        currentSyncId = "00001";

        // Set the dummy data that will be sent to firebase
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.put(currentSyncId, "Hello, world!");

        // Sync dummy data to firebase
        mFirebaseMain2014.updateChildren(map);

        Log.d("MAIN", "Sync called.");
    }


    /**
     * Print the contents of global currentSyncId
     */
    public void printId(){
        Log.d("MAIN", "PRINTING CURRENT id value: " + currentSyncId + ", userid: " + getAuthUserId());
    }


    public String getAuthUserId(){
        return mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }
}
```

**TEST FLOW**

1. Loaded the app
2. Pressed the `R.id.btn_echovalue` button
3. Pressed the `R.id.btn_sync` button
4. Pressed the `R.id.btn_echovalue` button

**LOG OUTPUT**

```
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( WN1b3pJyggNOvaoHDdtPsHrFLmG3 ).
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
               Notified 0 auth state listeners.
D/MAIN: A user was logged in: WN1b3pJyggNOvaoHDdtPsHrFLmG3
D/MAIN: Initialized databases
W/SyncTree: Listen at /2014/app_final/WN1b3pJyggNOvaoHDdtPsHrFLmG3 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
D/MAIN-ON-CANCELLED-EVENT: An error occurred while syncing data: Permission denied
                            id: Hello!!!
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
                [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( WN1b3pJyggNOvaoHDdtPsHrFLmG3 ).
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
               Notified 1 auth state listeners.
D/MAIN: PRINTING CURRENT id value: Hello!!!, userid: WN1b3pJyggNOvaoHDdtPsHrFLmG3
D/MAIN: Initiating sync...
D/MAIN: Sync called.
W/RepoOperation: updateChildren at /2014 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
D/MAIN: PRINTING CURRENT id value: 00001, userid: WN1b3pJyggNOvaoHDdtPsHrFLmG3
```

The Log inside `onCancelled()` was firing well. I expect to see

```
MAIN: An error occurred while syncing data: Permission denied.
Sync ID: 0001
```

But instead, I see:

```
MAIN: An error occurred while syncing data: Permission denied.
Sync ID: Hello!!!
```

I need to keep track of the `currentSyncId` when the `onCancelled()` was fired so I can reset its local sync status references in the app to `false`.

I have looked for similar cases and questions but the closest threads I found are how to call `onCancelled` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789400/method-oncancelled-is-never-used-in-firebase) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener), and a few references to [onDataChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021378/android-firebase-ondatachange-and-oncancelled-not-being-called-with-no-int). I found an interesting answer by [@vincrichaud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5914654/vincrichaud) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791820/why-global-variable-does-not-update-with-global-function-within-the-same-global), but I'm not really sure if this is applicable to firebase android as well.

TIA!

Comment: Please edit your question to show a complete example, not just a few snippets.  It's impossible to imagine the interactions between everything without all the code.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @DougStevenson and Alex Mamo I have just replaced the snippets with the complete sample.

Comment: Put log lines in every single method.  Look at the order in which they occur.  What does that tell you about how things work?

Comment: Hi, I've added logs and modified the code samples some more. I see it seems `onCancelled` was called only once on `onCreate()` and never again. But where does the `W/RepoOperation: updateChildren at /2014 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied` gets called? I think its this that I want to catch. Thanks @DougStevenson

Comment: onCancelled isn't called *during* onCreate.  It's called *after* onCreate, because the listener is asynchronous.